# How to find an exact solution to this ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I am trying to find an exact solution to this differential equation,

```
ode = f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] - f'[x]^2 == 0
```

For which, I already know the exact solution exist in the form,

```
Exactsol = (1 - Exp[-x])

Simplify[ode /. {{f[x] -> %}} /. {{f'[x] -> D[%, x]}} /. {{f''[x] -> 
       D[%, x, x]}} /. {{f'''[x] -> D[%, x, x, x]}}] // Flatten
```

But `DSolve` is unable to find any closed form solution to this ode.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Exactsol = (-r - Exp[r x])` also produces True.

Comment: A still more general solution is `Exactsol = c1 + c2 Exp[-c1 x]`.